# Cplusplus.com - is it bad to use links from it to answer?

Tags: discussion

I was reading this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226143/formatting-output-in-c), and one of the answers provided a link to [Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/). That answer got a down vote with a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226143/formatting-output-in-c#comment14744856_11226340) saying " -1 for link to cplusplus.com."

the comment provided a [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com) but it is expired. 
Is there something wrong with using that website as a reference for answers ?

Comment: Note: the real problem is that link-only answers are *not* answers. The answerer should have at least copy-pasted the fundamental information in its answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu Link-only answers *are* answers, just not particularly good ones.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Given a question on a certain topic an answer should be valid independently of the time it was posted *if the topic hasn't changed*. Link-only answers do *not* have this fundamental property. A link-only answer posted today could be completely useless tomorrow. I believe that the action of flagging an answer should not depend on when the link is going to rot. If the writer doesn't even put the effort of copy-pasting the most brief summary, its answer isn't worth the upvotes and should just be a comment.

Comment: @Bakuriu If the link hasn't rotted yet, don't flag for a moderator. You can downvote, comment, edit all you want. You have other tools to fix that answer. It doesn't require a moderator's attention.